# New to SQL, getting 'Missing Keyword' error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT N.ROOM_NUMBER AS "ROOM",
       T.SLEEPS AS "SLEEPS",
       G.FAMILY_NAME || ',' || G.GIVEN_NAME
  FROM ((((A2_GUEST G 
      JOIN A2_BOOKING B ON (G.GUEST_ID = B.GUEST)) 
      JOIN A2_RESERVATION 
      JOIN A2_ROOM N ON (N.ROOM_NUMBER = R.ROOM_NUMBER)) 
      JOIN A2_ROOM_TYPE T ON (N.ROOM_TYPE = R.ROOM_TYPE)) 
 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 50 Column: 50

Brand new to SQL, trying to query a database. I'm probably just being stupid with syntax but I'll greatly appreciate any help.

Expected to get a list of all the rooms which have been booked for a certain date, with the room number and how many can sleep in the room. Also the name of the guest who made the booking and the date of when the booking was made.

Comment: At a glimpse, the `SELECT...FROM` is missing just before `A2_GUEST`. Formatting the statement is recommended forever. This way you can catch the issue easier.

Comment: How should `A2_RESERVATION` be JOINed to the other tables?

Comment: Skip the parentheses.

Comment: Your join to `a2_room_type t` should use a column of `t`, not `n.room_type = r.room_type`.

Answer (score 2):

- You do not need the parentheses around the joins (they are not invalid syntax **if** you make sure each opening brace has a matching closing brace [which yours doesn't] but, in this case, they do not add anything to the query except confusion).
- You have not got an `R` alias (presumably on the `A2_RESERVATION` table).
- You do not specify a `JOIN` condition for the `A2_RESERVATION` table (either use `INNER JOIN` and include the `ON` clause or use `CROSS JOIN`).

Something like:

```sql
SELECT N.ROOM_NUMBER AS ROOM,
       T.SLEEPS,
       G.FAMILY_NAME || ',' || G.GIVEN_NAME
  FROM A2_GUEST G 
       INNER JOIN A2_BOOKING B     ON G.GUEST_ID = B.GUEST
       CROSS JOIN A2_RESERVATION R
       INNER JOIN A2_ROOM N        ON N.ROOM_NUMBER = R.ROOM_NUMBER
       INNER JOIN A2_ROOM_TYPE T   ON N.ROOM_TYPE = R.ROOM_TYPE
 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

or:

```sql
SELECT N.ROOM_NUMBER AS ROOM,
       T.SLEEPS,
       G.FAMILY_NAME || ',' || G.GIVEN_NAME
  FROM A2_GUEST G 
       INNER JOIN A2_BOOKING B     ON G.GUEST_ID = B.GUEST
       INNER JOIN A2_RESERVATION R ON R.something = B.something
       INNER JOIN A2_ROOM N        ON N.ROOM_NUMBER = R.ROOM_NUMBER
       INNER JOIN A2_ROOM_TYPE T   ON N.ROOM_TYPE = R.ROOM_TYPE
 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```